# Why does my function not end when a return is stated (Node.js and Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to write a POST endpoint using Node and Express that creates a new account for a user. In my function, I'm doing 2 database calls. The first one checks to make sure the email the user sent in the request does not exist in the database and the second one inserts the user if the first function comes back as false:

```
        UserService.checkDupEmail(db, user.email)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result === true) {
                    const message = 'Email already exists.';
                    return res
                        .status(400)
                        .json('Error: ' + message)
                };
            });
        
        const table = 'users';
        BaseService.post(db, table, user)
            .then((user) => {
                Response.created(res, user);
            })
            .catch(next)
```

If the first call comes back as true meaning, the email already exists, I want to immediately return the response with an error code and a JSON message stating that the email exists. What's happening is that the response is being sent but the function continues to try to do the second database call which of course fails because the email already exists.

If I'm not mistaken, I believe this is how Express and middleware are supposed to work right? It's supposed to be a chain of validations and middleware that as long as they pass, it continues going down the chain until the last CRUD operation?

Comment: The function *which is the `.then()` callback* does end immediately. However, terminating that function doesn't terminate the outer function much the same way that `foo(); return true;` doesn't end with `foo()` if that one contains a `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware chains don't continue automatically in Express.js unless you call the next variable provided as shown below:

```
router.post('/createUser', function (req, res, next) { next(); }
```

As you create a promise the return only belongs to the promise not ending the execution of your Express function. As you are checking for the `result === true`, I would create an else for the execution of not finding the result in the database and add the new user there. I'd change your code to:

```
    UserService.checkDupEmail(db, user.email)
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result === true) {
                        const message = 'Email already exists.';
                        return res
                            .status(400)
                            .json('Error: ' + message)
                    } else {
                       const table = 'users';
                       BaseService.post(db, table, user)
                         .then((user) => {
                             Response.created(res, user);
                          })
                         .catch(next)
                   }
                }).catch(next){

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

UserService.checkDupEmail(db, user.email) returns a promise. Callback added with then() will be invoked after the completion of the UserService.checkDupEmail.

```
    (result) => {
        if (result === true) {
            const message = 'Email already exists.';
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json('Error: ' + message)
        };
    }
```

above is your callback function.

the return you are talking about is the return of the callback function.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises